# Interchanging two keys in vimvscode

Tags: vscode-extensions, vim-plugin

I've been trying to customize my vimvscode experience, so far going good. But I ran into an issue while trying to swap around the functionality of <kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>;</kbd> the same way I did for <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd>.

I tried to do it the same way I did for <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd>. See picture and snippet below:

[settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okyTt.png)

```
"vim.insertModeKeyBindings":[
        {"before":["j","k"],"after":["<Esc>"]}
    ],
    "vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
        {"before":["<C-u>zz"],"after":["<C-u>"]},
        {"before":["<C-d>zz"],"after":["<C-d>"]},
    ],
    "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {"before":["j"],"after":["k"]},
        {"before":["k"],"after":["j"]},
        {"before":[";"],"after":[","]},
        {"before":[","],"after":[";"]},
    ],
    "vim.visualModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {"before":["j"],"after":["k"]},
        {"before":["k"],"after":["j"]},
        {"before":[";"],"after":[","]},
        {"before":[","],"after":[";"]},
    ]
```

Upon using it, I see that I have different behavior weather I use forward jump inline <kbd>f</kbd> (undesired) to backwards jump <kbd>F</kbd> (desired). Even if I invert the order, I still get always the same outcome of inconsistent and backwards behavior.

Any advice would be appreciated.